# Background-size wont update on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I dont know why but when I try to use hover event on CSS and Jquery .css for some reason it will not update the text. My plan is to make one of those slide show that you see text on the picture and on hover more text will show up.I need the background because of the pictures color and I dont want to make it big and on hover it will show text I want it to start from small. I dont care if its made by Jquery CSS or whatever.My end goal will be also to animate it as far as I know with Jquery it easiest but I can also do CSS

```js
$("#ShortText").css({
    fontSize:screen.height*.015,
    //right: screen.width * .18,
    //top: screen.height * .585,
    width:screen.width * .6,
    right: screen.width * .2,
    top:screen.height*.65
});
```

```css
#ShortText{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0,.6);
}

#Hide{
    display:none
}

#ShortText:hover{
    background:blue;
    background-size:100% 100%;   
    position:absolute;
}

#First:hover + #Hovered1{
    display:block
}

body{
    color:white
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div id="ShortText">
        <div>
            <h1 id="First">1</h1>
            <p id="Hovered1">Hoverd </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1 id="Second">2</h1>
            <p id="Hovered2">Hoverd </p>
        </div>
        <div>
            <h1 id="Third">3</h1>
            <p id="Hovered3">Hoverd </p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `top` and `right` you need `position: absolute`:

```js
$("#ShortText").css({
  fontSize:screen.height*.015,
  right: screen.width * .18,
  top: screen.height * .585,
  width:screen.width * .6
});
```

```css
#ShortText{
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0,.6);
}
#Hide{
  display:none
}
#ShortText:hover{
  background:blue;
  background-size:100% 100%;   
  position: absolute;
}
#First:hover + #Hovered1{
  display:block
}
body{
  color:white
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ShortText">
  <div >
    <h1 id="First">1</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1 id="Second">2</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1 id="Third">3</h1>

  </div>
</div>
<div id="Hide">
  <p id="Hovered1">Hoverd </p>
  <p id="Hovered2">Hoverd </p>
  <p id="Hovered3">Hoverd </p>
</div>
```

**Your Issue Updated**

1. The `#First:hover + #Hovered1` will select nothing because the `#Hovered1` is not an immediate sibling of the `#First`.
2. `#Hide` is always hidden, so if you are trying to show something inside it, the parent is still hidden, so are the children.
3. Change your approach totally.

Comment: The position is not my problem my problem is that a) if you look Im trying to show other id on hover b)the size of the background wont update(I updated the fiddle link to use the position absolute)

Comment: @saarsc Got your issue.

Comment: @saarsc See the update. Will add a new snippet to work.

Comment: Wait so I need to 
1.Remove the Hide id 
2.Insert the text I want to show to the text that need to be hovered div?